# Uber API 'fare_id' usage

Tags: uber-api

We're working on a new web application using the Uber API and had a couple questions concerning the use of 'fare_id'

1. Is “fare_id” is a required parameter for POST /requests Api call? Can we pass empty value for fare_id and book a request?
2. What should be passed for “fare_id” in the ride request api for product that involves Surge Pricing?

Thanks

Comment: i have a similar question: 

how to book a ride with 1.2. e.g. in vienna/austria where upfront_fare_enable is false and not fare_id is provided as part of the request API response?

Answer (score 0):

The Fare ID was introduced with the concept of Upfront Fares ([as part of the announcement of v1.2 endpoints of the Uber API](https://medium.com/uber-developers/announcing-riders-api-1-2-featuring-upfront-fares-ride-promotions-and-improved-dev-docs-7745135ca33f#.o8tdvsgvw)). Upfront fares replace the concept of surge pricing to follow a dynamic pricing concept. You [*have* to pass](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-post) such an ID if you use v1.2 endpoints. However, if you are still [using v1.0 of the Uber API](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1/requests-post), the Fare ID is optional and mostly useful for UberPOOL.

To obtain a Fare ID, you have to follow the best practices of [Upfront Pricing](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/api/best-practices#upfront-fares).

Answer (score -1):

We successfully tested in the sandbox with setting fare_id to null in the cases described (using the java sdk).

Comment: As of v1.2, the sandbox will allow a null fare_id but production requests will fail.